# Download generated excel file using xslxwriter on Python(Django)

Tags: python, django, excel

I am working with Python using the Django framework, at this moment I am generating some reports in Excel, for that I use the xslxwriter library, the user tries to download the file from the platform, I do not get the download and instead it The answer is strange characters, I think that's the Excel file, anyway I don't know how to make that file download.

This snippet is the one that is supposed to download the file

```
    workbook.close()
    output.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"
    output.close()
    return response
```

This is the response I get from the frontend
[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You may have to set the `Content-Type` response header. Also, your "strange characters" don't look very strange to me. You can expect to see some strange symbols when you're asking a text-viewer to interpret binary data, and as far as I know the headers for the `.xlsx` file-extensions are pretty beefy. It's basically a glorified zip file with various `.xml` files embedded inside, along with other resources. You weren't really expecting to see plaintext, like in a `.csv`, were you?

Comment: What I want to do is download the excel file generated by the system, but that is what I am getting.

Comment: Now i´m getting <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x7f9c2af0ce80> on Response